# How to join arrays in a generic fashion way?

Tags: c#, arrays, concatenation

I want to join arrays independently of their types.

```cs
T[] arr1 = new T[];
T[] arr2 new T[];
T[] newArr = Helper.GetJoint(arr1, arr2);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use LINQ for that

```
 T[] newArr = arr1.Concat(arr2).ToArray();
```

For larger arrays, where you want the allocation to be optimized, you can use the following extension method

```
public static T[] Append<T>(this ICollection<T> arr1, ICollection<T> arr2) {
    var newArr = new T[arr1.Count + arr2.Count];
    arr1.CopyTo(newArr, 0);
    arr2.CopyTo(newArr, arr1.Count);
    return newArr;
}
```

This can be called below

```
var newArr = arr1.Append(arr2);
```

Comment: I mentioned this option in my answer and also is the worst option in perf cases.